# Docker name resolution error

Tags: dns, docker

I have an enviroment with two different containers deployed in the same network and both have a web service up in differents ports.

The problem is that from one of them i can resolve name of the another one, but
by the other way it doesnt work:

From ONE to TWO:

```
user@ONE:/opt/directory$ curl -XGET http://TWO:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to TWO port 8080: Connection refused
```

FROM TWO to ONE:

```
user@TWO:/opt/directory$ curl -XGET http://ONE:443
{"detail":"The requested URL / was not found.","status":404,"title":"Not Found","type":"about:blank"}
```

If i try to do the same curl but using de container IP, it's work:

```
curl -XGET http://172.19.0.10:443
{"detail":"The requested URL / was not found.","status":404,"title":"Not Found","type":"about:blank"}
```

The /etc/resolv.conf is the same in both containers:

```
search eu-west-1.compute.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options timeout:2 attempts:5 ndots:0
```

The docker-compose of both are the same and using the same image..So i don't know where could be the problem..

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) the important file is the `/etc/hosts` of each container  2) you should have one single `docker-compose` file that starts both, that's how they are started with info to find each other.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the issue since the 3rd example is missing a source hostname, and there is no description of which container that IP belongs to. It looks like you are connecting to the wrong port. Please show what happens if you attempt to run `curl -XGET http://TWO:443`. We need to know if these containers are on the same *user created* network, or if you are using something like the default docker bridge. I'd also recommend against using 443 for http instead of https.

Comment: The problem is solved. I've changed the name and hostname of the container and it works!